# Date.now() returning NaN in PhoneGap

Tags: date, cordova

I can't seem to get the timestamp in my phonegap application. A simple call to Date.now(), e.g. the following, results in NaN.

```
console.log("lastEditedOn: " + Date.now().toString() );
```

LogCat:

```
01-26 18:28:59.997: I/Web Console(17970): LastEditedOn: NaN:220
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Cheers,
Don

Comment: Have you tried dimensioning the date first?

Comment: What do you mean to dimension the date first? (Sorry, quite new to javascript).

Comment: `var d = new Date()` then `d.now()` you shouldn't really need to, I would have thought, but it may be worth a go.

Comment: Okay, managed to get it with the following: var d = new Date();
        var lastEditedOn;
        lastEditedOn = d.getTime();

Comment: Excellent!  Should have posted this as an answer!  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the correct timestamp with this:

```
var d = new Date();
var lastEditedOn;
lastEditedOn = d.getTime();
console.log(lastEditedOn);
```

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly toString the Date.now() because it returns the milliseconds from midnight, Jan 1 1970.

You need to convert them  like this:

```
function printDate() {
var temp = new Date();
var dateStr = padStr(temp.getFullYear()) +
              padStr(1 + temp.getMonth()) +
              padStr(temp.getDate()) +
              padStr(temp.getHours()) +
              padStr(temp.getMinutes()) +
              padStr(temp.getSeconds());
debug (dateStr );
}

function padStr(i) {
return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
}
```

Comment: It is the milliseconds from midnight, Jan 1 1970 I am looking for.